# Selecionar varias tablas en androis con cursor

Tags: android

Estoy programando en Android studio y me ha surguido un problema.
Estoy intentando con un cursor selecionar con una consulta varias tablas, pero me da un error de ejecución al hacer la consulta, se me sale del programa. También probado con INNER JOIN

```
         Cursor cursorjornadas = databasjornadas.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + InContract.NUMJornadasColumnas.TABLA_NUMJORNADAS + "AS TN, "
                        + InContract.JornadasColumnas.TABLA_JORNADAS + "AS TJ,  " + InContract.CamposColumnas.TABLA_CAMPOS + "AS TC, "
                        + InContract.EquiposColumnas.TABLA_EQUIPOS + "AS TEL, "
                        + InContract.EquiposColumnas.TABLA_EQUIPOS + "AS TEV "
                        + " WHERE  TN.IDDIV  =  " + diviid + " AND TN-IDNJOR  = TJ.IDNJOR AND TN.NJORNADAS  = " + NumJornadas 
                        + " AND TC.IDCAMPO  = TJ.IDCAMPO AND TEL.IDEQUI  = TJ.EQUIPOl AND TEV.IDEQUI = TJ.EQUIPOV", null);
```

El error que sale en tiempo de ejecucion es :

> 2019-12-16 09:19:28.231 1985-2076/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '6d9aa
>   com.valhondo.delgado.fsmerida/com.valhondo.delgado.fsmerida.MainActivity
>   (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
>   2019-12-16 09:19:28.286 1985-3079/? E/ActivityTrigger:
>   activityResumeTrigger: not
>   whiteListedcom.android.launcher3/com.android.a1launcher.AndroidOneLauncher/28
>   2019-12-16 09:19:28.287 568-620/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile
>   no. 0, total profiles 0 only 2019-12-16 09:19:28.291 568-620/?
>   E/ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource
>   /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,llccbw/min_freq not supported 2019-12-16
>   09:19:28.291 568-620/? E/ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply
>   optimization [12, 0] 2019-12-16 09:19:28.292 568-620/?
>   E/ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Failed to read
>   /sys/class/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/force_no_nap 2019-12-16 09:19:28.292
>   568-620/? E/ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [10, 7]
>   2019-12-16 09:19:28.464 544-11782/? E/msm8916_platform:
>   platform_get_snd_device_backend_index: BE DAI Name Table is not
>   present 2019-12-16 09:19:28.465 544-11782/? E/audio_hw_utils:
>   send_app_type_cfg_for_device: Couldn't get the backend index for snd
>   device voice-rec-mic ret=-14 2019-12-16 09:19:28.466 544-11782/?
>   E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19 2019-12-16
>   09:19:28.466 544-11782/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error:
>   ACDB_CMD_GET_AFE_COMMON_TABLE_SIZE Returned = -19 2019-12-16
>   09:19:28.466 544-11782/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AFE returned = -19
>   2019-12-16 09:19:28.472 11783-11783/? E/d.process.acor: Not starting
>   debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent. 2019-12-16
>   09:19:28.500 11708-11761/? E/native: model-utils.cc:47 Not a valid
>   Model flatbuffer 2019-12-16 09:19:28.500 11708-11761/? E/native:
>   model-provider-from-fb.cc:102 Unable to initialize
>   ModelProviderFromFlatbuffer 2019-12-16 09:19:28.786 915-956/?
>   E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
>   2019-12-16 09:19:53.939 908-5308/? E/DnsTlsSocket: Failed to increment
>   eventfd by -9223372036854775808 2019-12-16 09:19:54.000 908-5307/?
>   E/DnsTlsSocket: Failed to increment eventfd by -9223372036854775808
>   2019-12-16 09:20:11.020 908-1072/? E/NetlinkEvent:
>   NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'INTERFACE' not found 2019-12-16
>   09:20:11.021 908-1072/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam():
>   Parameter 'STATE' not found 2019-12-16 09:20:11.021 908-1072/?
>   E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'TIME_NS' not
>   found 2019-12-16 09:20:11.021 908-1072/? E/NetlinkEvent:
>   NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found 2019-12-16
>   09:20:16.211 908-1072/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam():
>   Parameter 'INTERFACE' not found 2019-12-16 09:20:16.211 908-1072/?
>   E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'STATE' not found
>   2019-12-16 09:20:16.211 908-1072/? E/NetlinkEvent:
>   NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'TIME_NS' not found 2019-12-16
>   09:20:16.211 908-1072/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam():
>   Parameter 'UID' not found 2019-12-16 09:20:21.395 908-1072/?
>   E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'INTERFACE' not
>   found 2019-12-16 09:20:21.395 908-1072/? E/NetlinkEvent:
>   NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'STATE' not found 2019-12-16
>   09:20:21.395 908-1072/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam():
>   Parameter 'TIME_NS' not found 2019-12-16 09:20:21.395 908-1072/?
>   E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
>   2019-12-16 09:20:26.558 908-1072/? E/NetlinkEvent:
>   NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'INTERFACE' not found 2019-12-16
>   09:20:26.558 908-1072/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam():
>   Parameter 'STATE' not found 2019-12-16 09:20:26.558 908-1072/?
>   E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'TIME_NS' not
>   found 2019-12-16 09:20:26.558 908-1072/? E/NetlinkEvent:
>   NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found 2019-12-16
>   09:20:28.787 915-956/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result
>   NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0 2019-12-16 09:20:31.732 908-1072/?
>   E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'INTERFACE' not
>   found 2019-12-16 09:20:31.732 908-1072/? E/NetlinkEvent:
>   NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'STATE' not found 2019-12-16
>   09:20:31.732 908-1072/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam():
>   Parameter 'TIME_NS' not found 2019-12-16 09:20:31.732 908-1072/?
>   E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
>   2019-12-16 09:20:36.009 11990-11990/? E/nectionsecurit: Not starting
>   debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
>
> d

---

Con INNER JOIN

```
 Cursor cursorjornadas = databasejornadas.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
                       + InContract.NUMJornadasColumnas.TABLA_NUMJORNADAS + " INNNER JOIN " + InContract.JornadasColumnas.TABLA_JORNADAS + " ON ("
                           + InContract.NUMJornadasColumnas.IDDIV  + " = " + InContract.JornadasColumnas.IDDIV + ") AND ("
                           + InContract.NUMJornadasColumnas.IDNJOR  + " = " + InContract.JornadasColumnas.IDNJOR + "), "

                       + InContract.JornadasColumnas.TABLA_JORNADAS + " INNNER JOIN " + InContract.CamposColumnas.TABLA_CAMPOS
                           + " ON (" + InContract.JornadasColumnas.IDCAMPO + " = " + InContract.CamposColumnas.IDCAMPO + ", "

                        + InContract.JornadasColumnas.TABLA_JORNADAS + " INNNER JOIN " + InContract.EquiposColumnas.TABLA_EQUIPOS + " ON ("
                           + InContract.JornadasColumnas.EQUIPOl + " = " + InContract.EquiposColumnas.IDEQUI + "), "

                       + InContract.JornadasColumnas.TABLA_JORNADAS + " INNNER JOIN " + InContract.EquiposColumnas.TABLA_EQUIPOS + "  ON ("
                                + InContract.JornadasColumnas.EQUIPOV + " = " + InContract.EquiposColumnas.IDEQUI +  ") "

                        + " WHERE (" + InContract.NUMJornadasColumnas.IDDIV + " =  " + diviid + ") AND ("
                                     + InContract.NUMJornadasColumnas.NJORNADAS  + " = " + NumJornadas + ") ", null);
```

El error es en tiempo de ejecucion:

```
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: El SQL esta mal deberías usar INNER JOIN para hacer los match entre las tablas o en caso que no haya usar UNION

Comment: Lo intento y comento. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Si sigues con problemas pon las relaciones entre las tables y lo miro con mas detalle

Comment: @FernandoDelgadoFernandez , agrega espacios en los " AS" ya que si no agregas espacio esta generando tu Query incorrectamente, Puedes imprimir tu consulta para verificarla, revisa mi respuesta.

Comment: @FernandoDelgadoFernandez cuando busques un error en el LogCat,busca "Caused by", ahí se escribirá el bloque que describe puntualmente el problema. saludos.

Answer (score 2):

El LogCat no indica en realidad el problema, probablemente se encuentra en otro bloque de información.

Para realizar una consulta de varias tablas puedes realizarlo como lo tienes en tu pregunta o con  INNER JOIN como indicas, pero en este caso puedo identificar un problema.

Cuando concatenas `"AS TN, "`,  `"AS TJ,  "`, `"AS TC, "`, `"AS TEL, "` y  `"AS TEV "`, no estas agregando un espacio, lo cual va a provocar que tu query sea incorrecto, lo tendrías que realizar de esta forma:

```
 Cursor cursorjornadas = databasjornadas.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + InContract.NUMJornadasColumnas.TABLA_NUMJORNADAS + " AS TN, "
                + InContract.JornadasColumnas.TABLA_JORNADAS + " AS TJ,  " + InContract.CamposColumnas.TABLA_CAMPOS + " AS TC, "
                + InContract.EquiposColumnas.TABLA_EQUIPOS + " AS TEL, "
                + InContract.EquiposColumnas.TABLA_EQUIPOS + " AS TEV "
                + " WHERE  TN.IDDIV  =  " + diviid + " AND TN-IDNJOR  = TJ.IDNJOR AND TN.NJORNADAS  = " + NumJornadas 
                + " AND TC.IDCAMPO  = TJ.IDCAMPO AND TEL.IDEQUI  = TJ.EQUIPOl AND TEV.IDEQUI = TJ.EQUIPOV", null);
```

---

Te recomiendo crees tu query en una  variable para poder imprimir su valor y verificar su correcta construcción, ejemplo:

```
//Crea Query
String myQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + InContract.NUMJornadasColumnas.TABLA_NUMJORNADAS + " AS TN, "
                + InContract.JornadasColumnas.TABLA_JORNADAS + " AS TJ,  " + InContract.CamposColumnas.TABLA_CAMPOS + " AS TC, "
                + InContract.EquiposColumnas.TABLA_EQUIPOS + " AS TEL, "
                + InContract.EquiposColumnas.TABLA_EQUIPOS + " AS TEV "
                + " WHERE  TN.IDDIV  =  " + diviid + " AND TN-IDNJOR  = TJ.IDNJOR AND TN.NJORNADAS  = " + NumJornadas 
                + " AND TC.IDCAMPO  = TJ.IDCAMPO AND TEL.IDEQUI  = TJ.EQUIPOl AND TEV.IDEQUI = TJ.EQUIPOV"

//Imprimes el query para verificarlo
System.out.println("Consulta: " + myQuery);

//Aplicas el Query para obtener un cursor.
     Cursor cursorjornadas = databasjornadas.rawQuery(myQuery, null);
```